# Content beneath app bar is not shrinking in material ui

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, material-ui

I have added two navBar one after another, where the top Nav bar has a side drawer where the content beneath inside is shrining on clicking toggle button. While in other hand i am displaying another Nav bar beneath first nav bar, it also has a side drawer but while toggling it the content inside is not shrinking. I have tried that in all possible ways. Pls help me to fix that. Here i ma sharing the code sandbox link for that.https://codesandbox.io/s/persistentdrawer-pygrt?file=/PersistentDrawer.js

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide a [mre], not a link to another site that has your code.

Comment: Not a solution, but if you remove the map's style `width` inside the dev tools of your browser, it works as normal.